# Could this bluescreen of death from my audio driver be caused by my keyboard filter driver?

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod

After installing a custom keyboard filter driver (`kbfiltr.sys`), a slightly modified version of [kbfiltr](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/input/kbfiltr/sys) (Windows-driver-samples), and waking my system from standby the next morning, I was greeted by this BSOD:

```
Bug Check String  DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL 
Bug Check Code    0x000000d1    
Parameter 1       00000000`00000000 
Parameter 2       00000000`00000002 
Parameter 3       00000000`00000000 
Parameter 4       fffff801`7675cd91 
Caused By Driver  cmudaxp.sys   
Caused By Address cmudaxp.sys+2f7d91    
Crash Address     ntoskrnl.exe+1402a0
```

Edit: Here are all drivers found in stack by BlueScreenView

```
Filename      Address in Stack
cmudaxp.sys   cmudaxp.sys+2f7d91    
ntoskrnl.exe  ntoskrnl.exe+1e448b
```

This BSOD seems to be a well known [Asus Xonar audio driver bug](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cmudaxp.sys+DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL), but it

- never occured to me before during the whole 5 years of running my current setup
- just happened the day after installing my new custom driver

Since the BSOD happened, I've woken up my system from standby several times **without any errors**.

Is this purely a very unfortunate coincidence or is there a chance it might have been caused by my driver (`kbfiltr.sys`)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would be better to ask how to identify the cause of your problem rather than ask if you're correct that the cause is X. See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Comment: I currently have no reproducible problem. I'm asking whether the BSOD info regarding the problematic driver could be misleading. Could `kbfiltr.sys` in any way cause a `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` exception in `cmudaxp.sys`?

Comment: It *could* be misleading. But with the information we have no one here can say for certain. Answers on this site are expected to be definitive, so questions that largely invite speculation are off topic.

Comment: Use [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to analyze the crashes. Add the info to your post to be analyzed. In general, if it's caused by a driver, the driver will be on the top of the stack.

Comment: I've added the stack entries from BSV. The probability that this is related to `kbfiltr.sys` is rather low, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up: During the last 8 days, and without changing the system, I didn't get any more BSODs.
It's highly probable that this single BSOD was just a very unlucky coincidence.